# Why do I have ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path in my Spring Boot Rest Data Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have done nothing special until now, but got this annoying Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/directoryWatches': {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException, public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException}

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class DirectoryWatch {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String name;
//setters, getters and default constructor...
}
```

And my DirectoryWatchRepository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface DirectoryWatchRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DirectoryWatch, Long> {
}
```

The exception occurs, when I open the HAL Browser and try to open the NON-GET HTTP Methods:
[image]

Snippets of my pom file:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.M2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

Dependencies:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-docs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Has anyone a helping idea?

Thank you,
Christian

Comment: Please add relevant snippet of your POM or state the versions of the artifacts used.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Added pom deps.

Comment: @Chrisposure can you add your controller code
?

Comment: There is no controller Code. I use @RepositoryRestResource from Spring Data Rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suspiciously looks like the regression in Spring Framework 4.3 RC1 that I've reported [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14182). The issue is already fixed and the upcoming Spring Boot 1.4 M3 is going to include the fixed version.

The release Boot should be available in a couple of days. Until that has happened you could just manually upgrade to Spring Framework 4.3 RC2.

Comment: @Chrisposure — 1.4 M3 is there with the issue fixed. 

Comment: @OliverGierke : I was trying one of your GitHub project on spring boot microservices, got a similar type of ambiguous handler error. The code is working fine if version downgraded to 1.4 M1 but not using 1.4 M3. Could you please suggest, is there any other changes required as m getting some error.Raised same issue in Github tracker and even suggested my solution for that.Please advise how to resolve the issue for M3 or 1.4 RELEASE version.

Comment: Make sure you use Spring Framework 4.3 GA or newer. (Boot 1.4 defaults to 4.3.2).